# Many-to-Many relationships Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited

Tags: python, django, django-models, relationship

Ive created a few models, one with a many to many relationship.

```
class PBSItems(models.Model):
    PBSCode = models.CharField(max_length=6, primary_key=True)
    RestrictFlag = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    eAuthQuant = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.PBSCode

class Restrictions(models.Model):
    IndicatId = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    RestrictFullText = models.CharField(max_length=17040)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.IndicatId

class Drug(models.Model):
    PBSCode = models.ForeignKey(PBSItems, null=True, on_delete = models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.PBSCode

class Links(models.Model):
    PBSCode = models.ManyToManyField(Drug)
    IndicatId = models.ForeignKey(Restrictions, on_delete = models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.IndicatId
```

However, once I create the instances for PBSItems, Restrictions and Drug, and I try and create the instance for Links, I get the following message:

```
TypeError: Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use PBSCode.set() instead.
```

How do I use PBSCode.set() in the model, or how do I get around this issue?

Many thanks

EDIT:

I am using managment commands to create the instances

Load_Links

```
from csv import DictReader
import csv, os
from datetime import datetime
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from myapp.models import Links, PBSItems
from pytz import UTC

class Command(BaseCommand):

    def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
        now = datetime.now()
        yearid=str(now.year)
        monthid= now.month
        if monthid<10:
            monthid="0"+str(monthid)
        else:
            monthid=str(monthid)
        fN_Link = os.path.join("data - "+yearid+monthid+"01"+"\\LinkExtract_"+yearid+monthid+"01.txt")
        print(fN_Link)
        with open(fN_Link) as file:
            Link_reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter='\t')
            for row  in Link_reader:
                links = Links()
                if row != []:
                    links.PBSCode, _ = PBSItems.objects.get_or_create(PBSCode = row[0])
                    links.IndicatId = row[1].strip()
                    links.save()
        self.stdout.write(self.style.SUCCESS('Data imported successfully'))
```

Load_Restrictions

```
from csv import DictReader
import csv, os
from datetime import datetime
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from myapp.models import Restrictions
from pytz import UTC

class Command(BaseCommand):

    def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
        now = datetime.now()
        yearid=str(now.year)
        monthid= now.month
        if monthid<10:
            monthid="0"+str(monthid)
        else:
            monthid=str(monthid)
        fN_Restrict = os.path.join("data - "+yearid+monthid+"01"+"\\RestrictionExtract_"+yearid+monthid+"01.txt")
        print(fN_Restrict)
        with open(fN_Restrict) as file:
            Restrict_reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter='\t')
            for row  in Restrict_reader:
                restrict = Restrictions()
                if row != []:
                    restrict.IndicatId1 = row[0]
                    restrict.RestrictFullText = row[1]
                    restrict.save()
        self.stdout.write(self.style.SUCCESS('Data imported successfully'))
```

Load_PBS_Items

```
from csv import DictReader
import csv, os
from datetime import datetime
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from myapp.models import PBSItems, PrescriberType, Note, Caution
from pytz import UTC
import pandas as pd

class Command(BaseCommand):

    def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
        now = datetime.now()
        yearid=str(now.year)
        monthid= now.month
        if monthid<10:
            monthid="0"+str(monthid)
        else:
            monthid=str(monthid)
        fN_PBSItems = os.path.join("data - "+yearid+monthid+"01"+"\\PBS_Item_Table_"+yearid+monthid+"01.txt")
        print(fN_PBSItems)
        df=pd.read_csv(fN_PBSItems,sep='\t', header=None)
        df.columns = ['PBSCode'] 
        df = df[df['EndDate'] =='        ']
        for index, row in df.iterrows():
            pbsitems = PBSItems()
            pbsitems.PBSCode = row[0]
            pbsitems.RestrictFlag = row[1]
            pbsitems.eAuthQuant = row[2]
            pbsitems.save()
        self.stdout.write(self.style.SUCCESS('Data imported successfully'))
```

Load_Drug

```
from csv import DictReader
import csv, os
from datetime import datetime

from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand

from myapp.models import Drug, PBSItems, Manfr, ATC
from pytz import UTC

class Command(BaseCommand):

    def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
        now = datetime.now()
        yearid=str(now.year)
        monthid= now.month
        if monthid<10:
            monthid="0"+str(monthid)
        else:
            monthid=str(monthid)
        fN_Drug = os.path.join("data - "+yearid+monthid+"01"+"\\drug_"+yearid+monthid+"01.txt")
        print(fN_Drug)
        with open(fN_Drug) as file:
            Drug_reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter='!')
            for row  in Drug_reader:
                drug = Drug()
                if row != []:
                    drug.ProgramCode = row[0]
                    drug.PBSCode, _  = PBSItems.objects.get_or_create(PBSCode = row[1])
                    drug.save()
        self.stdout.write(self.style.SUCCESS('Data imported successfully'))
```

EDIT(2): The recommended changes to the LoadLinks

```
from csv import DictReader
import csv, os
from datetime import datetime
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from myapp.models import Links, PBSItems, Restrictions
from pytz import UTC

class Command(BaseCommand):

    def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
        now = datetime.now()
        yearid=str(now.year)
        monthid= now.month
        if monthid<10:
            monthid="0"+str(monthid)
        else:
            monthid=str(monthid)
        fN_Link = os.path.join("data - "+yearid+monthid+"01"+"\\LinkExtract_"+yearid+monthid+"01.txt")
        print(fN_Link)
        with open(fN_Link) as file:
            Link_reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter='\t')
            for row  in Link_reader:
                links = Links()
                if row != []:
                    pbs_items, _ = PBSItems.objects.get_or_create(PBSCode = row[0])
                    links.PBSCode.append(pbs_items)
                    links.IndicatId = row[1].strip()
                    links.save()
```

Changes to the Links model

```
class Links(models.Model):
    PBSCode = models.ForeignKey(Drug, on_delete = models.PROTECT, null = True)
    #PBSCode = models.ManyToManyField(Drug)
    IndicatId = models.ForeignKey(Restrictions, on_delete = models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.IndicatId
```

Comment: Show us how you create the instances!

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
links.PBSCode, _ = PBSItems.objects.get_or_create(PBSCode = row[0])
```

You need to append or set the newly created PBSItems instance to `links.PBSCode`.

```
pbs_items, _ = PBSItems.objects.get_or_create(PBSCode = row[0])
links.PBSCode.append(pbs_items)
# Or if you want to reset the whole relationship to just this one instance
links.PBSCode.set([pbs_items])
```

Also, it's industry best practice to name fields in snake case such as `links.pbs_code`. As well as to name models as their singular instance where it makes sense. So `PBSItems` would be `PBSItem` and `Links` to `Link`. And finally when naming a ForeignKey relationship it's best to leave off the Id suffix if it's not necessary because when you access that property, it provides you with that relationship's instance. So `Link.IndicatId` would become `Link.indicat`.

Comment: ok, this is very helpful. I will rename the fields once I have this issue sorted. However, I have deleted the database and the migrations, ran the makemigrations, and migrate commands, and get to the issue of the links model with this error:
"myapp.Links: (fields.E336) The model is used as an intermediate model by 'myapp.Drug.intermediatefield', but it does not have a foreign key to 'Drug' or 'Restrictions'."
So I have changed the "PBSCode = models.ManyToManyField(Drug)" in the Links model to "PBSCode = models.ForeignKey(Drug, on_delete = models.PROTECT, null = True)".

Comment: Now when I run the model with the above recommendations I get the following error: "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'